# What's wrong with my PNG IDAT chunk?

Tags: image, png, zlib

I'm trying to manually construct a simple, 4x1, *uncompressed* PNG.

So far, I have:

```
89504E47  // PNG Header
0D0A1A0A

0000000D  // byte length of IHDR chunk contents, 4 bytes, value 13
49484452  // IHDR start - 4 bytes
00000004  // Width                        4 bytes }
00000001  // Height                       4 bytes }
08        // bit depth 8 = 24/32 bit      1 byte  }
06        // color type, 6 - RGBa         1 byte  }
00        // compression, 0 = Deflate     1 byte  }
00        // filter, 0 = no filter        1 byte  }
00        // interlace, 0 = no interlace  1 byte  } Total, 13 Bytes
F93C0FCD  // CRC of IHDR chunk, 4 bytes         

00000013  // byte length of IDAT chunk contents, 4 bytes, value 19
49444154  // IDAT start - 4 bytes
0000      // ZLib 0 compression,          2 bytes }
00        // Filter = 0,                  1 bytes }
CC0000FF  // Pixel 1, Red-ish,            4 bytes }
00CC00FF  // Pixel 2, Green-ish,          4 bytes }
0000CCFF  // Pixel 3, Blue-ish,           4 bytes }
CCCCCCCC  // Pixel 4, transclucent grey,  4 bytes } Total, 19 Bytes
6464C2B0  // CRC of IHDR chunk, 4 bytes

00000000  // byte length of IEND chunk, 4 bytes (value: 0)
49454E44  // IEND start - 4 bytes
AE426082  // CRC of IEND chunk, 4 bytes
```

---

## Update

I think the issue I'm having is down to the ZLib/Deflate ordering.

I think that I have to include the "Non-compressed blocks format" details from [RFC 1951, sec. 3.2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951), but I'm a little unsure as to the interactions. The only examples I can find are for Compressed blocks (understandably!)

So I've now tried:

```
49444154  // IDAT start - 4 bytes
01        // BFINAL = 1, BTYPE = 00       1 byte  }
11EE      // LEN & NLEN of data           2 bytes }
00        // Filter = 0,                  1 byte  }
CC0000FF  // Pixel 1, Red-ish,            4 bytes }
00CC00FF  // Pixel 2, Green-ish,          4 bytes }
0000CCFF  // Pixel 3, Blue-ish,           4 bytes }
CCCCCCCC  // Pixel 4, transclucent grey,  4 bytes } Total, 19 Bytes
6464C2B0  // CRC of IHDR chunk, 4 bytes
```

So the whole PNG file is:

```
89504E47    // PNG Block
0d0a1a0A

0000000D    // IHDR Block
49484452
00000004
00000001
08060000
00
F93C0FCD

00000014    // IDAT Block
49444154
0111EE00
CC0000FF
00CC00FF
0000CCFF
CCCCCCCC
6464C2B0

00000000    // IEND Block
49454E44
AE426082
```

I'd be really grateful for some pointers as to where the issue lies... or even the PNG data for a working file so that I can reverse-engineer it?

## Update 2

Thanks to Mark Adler, I've corrected my newbie errors, and now have functional code that can reproduce the result shown in his answer below, i.e. 4x1 pixel image. From this I can now happily produce a 100x1 image!

However, as a last step, I'd hoped, by tweaking the height field in the IHDR and adding additional non-terminal IDATs, to extend this to say a 4 x 2 image. Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work the way I'd expected.

I now have something like...

```
89504E47 // PNG Header
0D0A1A0A

0000000D // re calc'ed IHDR with 2 rows
49484452
00000004
00000002 // changed - now 2 rows
08
06
00
00
00
7FA87D63 // CRC of IHDR updated

0000001C // row 1 IDAT, non-terminal
49444154
7801
00       // BFINAL = 0, BTYPE = 00 
1100EEFF
00
CC0000FF
00CC00FF
0000CCFF
CCCCCCCC
3D3A0892
5D19A623


0000001C // row 2, terminal IDAT, as Mark Adler's answer
49444154
7801
01       // BFINAL = 1, BTYPE = 00 
1100EEFF
00
CC0000FF
00CC00FF
0000CCFF
CCCCCCCC
3D3A0892
BA0400B4

00000000
49454E44
AE426082
```

Comment: What about endian?

Comment: Nice thought - but even if it was the wrong way around, I should get *some* output ;-) no ?

Comment: Do not know, just asking... BTW, what output you expect, and from what software?

Comment: 4x1 pixel PNG red, green, blue, transparent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
11EE      // LEN & NLEN of data           2 bytes }
```

is wrong. `LEN` and `NLEN` are both 16 bits, not 8 bits. So that needs to be:

```
1100EEFF  // LEN & NLEN of data           4 bytes }
```

You also need a zlib wrapper around the deflate data. See RFC 1950.

Lastly you will need to update the CRC of the chunk. (Which has the wrong comment by the way -- it should say CRC of IDAT chunk.)

Thusly repaired:

```
89504E47  // PNG Header
0D0A1A0A

0000000D  // byte length of IHDR chunk contents, 4 bytes, value 13
49484452  // IHDR start - 4 bytes
00000004  // Width                        4 bytes }
00000001  // Height                       4 bytes }
08        // bit depth 8 = 24/32 bit      1 byte  }
06        // color type, 6 - RGBa         1 byte  }
00        // compression, 0 = Deflate     1 byte  }
00        // filter, 0 = no filter        1 byte  }
00        // interlace, 0 = no interlace  1 byte  } Total, 13 Bytes
F93C0FCD  // CRC of IHDR chunk, 4 bytes         

0000001C  // byte length of IDAT chunk contents, 4 bytes, value 28
49444154  // IDAT start - 4 bytes
7801      // zlib Header                  2 bytes }
01        // BFINAL = 1, BTYPE = 00       1 byte  }
1100EEFF  // LEN & NLEN of data           4 bytes }
00        // Filter = 0,                  1 byte  }
CC0000FF  // Pixel 1, Red-ish,            4 bytes }
00CC00FF  // Pixel 2, Green-ish,          4 bytes }
0000CCFF  // Pixel 3, Blue-ish,           4 bytes }
CCCCCCCC  // Pixel 4, transclucent grey,  4 bytes }
3d3a0892  // Adler-32 check               4 bytes }
ba0400b4  // CRC of IDAT chunk, 4 bytes

00000000  // byte length of IEND chunk, 4 bytes (value: 0)
49454E44  // IEND start - 4 bytes
AE426082  // CRC of IEND chunk, 4 bytes
```

Comment: Mark - genuinely honoured to have you answer this! thanks. I've re-written my code, (see above) and it now produces exactly the code you've provided above. Which is great! However, It was my intention to use additional, non-terminal IDATs to add multiple rows to the image. Unfortunately this fails.

Comment: The sequence of IDAT chunks must contain a _single_ zlib stream. Unfortunately, you can't just insert data in the middle of a zlib stream. At least not without updating the start and end of the zlib stream.

Comment: Ah ha! So I need to put the whole image into a single chunk?

Comment: Or ... you mean I can put the LEN and NLEN for the whole image in the first data chunk, and then divvy the rows up between chunks... I'll give it a go. Thanks again

Comment: No, you need to put the whole image into a single _zlib stream_. You can break up the zlib stream into multiple chunks, or put it all into a single chunk.

Comment: Thanks Mark. All working now, thanks to you and your example.

Comment: @Dycey Can you explain how you managed to add additional rows? (as you did not update your question)

Comment: This is a truly excellent answer for anyone implementing a PNG serializer and trying to get the first proof-of-concept off the ground. One example is worth a thousand pages of specs! A further helpful hint for others stumbling across this: `LEN` and `NLEN` are little-endian, contrary to everything else which is written out as big-endian (network byte order).